# Kivy Spinner's on_text seems to react only when the value changes

Tags: python, kivy

I want to print selected elements using Spinner.

I wrote the following test code.

**main.py**

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.properties import StringProperty 

class TextWidget(Widget):
    text = StringProperty()    # プロパティの追加

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = ''

    def print_text(self,text):        # ボタンをクリック時
        print(text)


class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = 'greeting'

    def build(self):
        return TextWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
TextWidget:

<TextWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        Spinner:
            id:softwarename_dropDownList
            size_hint: 1,0.3
            text: 'test1'
            values: 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'
            on_text: root.print_text(self.text)
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1,0.7
```

However, when starting the GUI, nothing is printed even if "test1" is selected in Spinner. When "test1" is selected again after selecting "test2", "test1" is printed.

[image]

Kivy Spinner's on_text seems to react only when the value changes.
Is there a way to react even if the value has not changed?

Comment: As you point out on_X it triggers when X changes. Could you explain yourself better, your question is confusing, when do you want the text to be printed?

Comment: I want to select Spinner immediately after starting the GUI and print "test1". But I can't do that.

Comment: Mmm, your explanation is not clear yet. Do you want it printed just after the GUI is displayed? Do you also want it to print as soon as the popup closes?

Comment: I want to print immediately after the popup closes, not just after the GUI is displayed.Immediately after starting the GUI, the value of Spinner is "test1". However, nothing is executed even if "test1" of Spinner is selected in this state. For example, I want to use Spinner to create something like a menu bar.

Comment: You can always set a blank/other text as default, so any selection will be changing its state...